# How do I position the navbar inside the header?

Tags: html, css

How do I position the navbar inside the header?  If I float the divs inside the header it works fine.  But when I remove the float the navbar positions below the header.  I dont understand it.  How do I fix it?

```css
html{
    height:100%;

}
body{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background-color: grey;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;

}
#container{
    height:90%;
    width:90%;
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-right: 5%;
    border-style: solid;

}
#header{
   height:8%;
   width:100%;

}
.logo{
    height:80%;
    width:10%;
}
.nav{
    height:90%;
    width:75%;
    margin:auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>basic</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
   <div id="container">
       <div id="header">
         <div class="logo">
         </div>
          <div class="nav">
              <a href=""></a>
              <a href=""></a>
              <a href=""></a>
              <a href=""></a>
          </div>
       </div>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

bydefault `div` element are block label element that's it took 100% width. 
you can change it's to 'inline' element using `float`, `inline-block`. >br/>
check updated snippet below

```css
html {
    height:100%;
}
body{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background-color: grey;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
#container{
    height:90%;
    width:90%;
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-right: 5%;
    border-style: solid;
}
#header{
    height:8%;
    width:100%;
}
.logo{
    height:80%;
    width:10%;
    display: inline-block;
}
.nav{
    height:90%;
    width:75%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="header">
        <div class="logo">logo</div>
        <div class="nav">
            <a href="">Nav1</a>
            <a href="">Nav2</a>
            <a href="">Nav3</a>
            <a href="">Nav4</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If u make the logo position:absolute it wont push down the navbar.
You do have to specify heigth and width since it will not compare to the parent div.

```
.logo{
  height:40px;
  width:100px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

An other way of fixing this is by giving a negavtive margin to the navbar.
This way you dont have to specify the width and heigth of the logo.

```
.nav{
  height:90%;
  width:75%;
  margin:-35px auto;
}
```